# OpenLDAP: Unable to add new LDAP attribute to schema

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am trying to add a new attribute to the OpenLDAP schema

```
# cat /etc/ldap/pwdResetAttribAdd.ldif
dn:  cn={3}inetorgperson,cn=schema,cn=config
add: olcAttributeTypes
##
## The new attribute type
##
olcAttributetypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.22
  NAME 'pwdReset'
  DESC 'The indication that the password has been reset'
  EQUALITY booleanMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.7
  SINGLE-VALUE
  USAGE directoryOperation )
```

The command I am using to add is as under

```
ldapmodify -D "cn=admin,dc=test" -w somePass -h localhost -p 389 -f /etc/ldap/pwdResetAttribAdd.ldif
```

However, it fails with below error

```
modifying entry "cn={3}inetorgperson,cn=schema,cn=config" ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
        additional info: olcAttributeTypes: "1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.22" is operational
```

**Where am I wrong ?**

Comment: Why? Just load `ppolicy.schema`.

Comment: @EJP I did not get you.. what should I do ?

Comment: What you should to is exactly what I said. Load `ppolicy.schema`. In the schema section of `slapd.conf` or the online configuration, whichever you're using. This is clearly mentioned in the documentation for what you're trying to do, i.e. implement the password-policy overlay, being where `pwdReset` comes from. No need for what you've posted above.

Comment: @EJP Where can I find ppolicy.schema ?

Comment: @EJP I found it at /etc/ldap/schema.. but it does not contain pwdReset attribute

Comment: Can we step back a minute and return to my first question. Why are you doing this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The file shown definitely is *not* in LDIF format.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this. Just add `ppolicy.schema` to the schemas being loaded, and the `ppolicy` overlay to the overlays, and all the appropriate `ppolicy` attributes will appear.

NB `pwdReset` and its friends that live in user entries are operational attributes and are commented out in this schema, but the `ppolicy` overlay causes them to be known anyway.

Comment: I have made an application, which sets this flag to true when admin resets password via my app. The app is generic in nature. It is failing in case of OpenLDAP coz of missing attribute, I want to add this attrib, to test my app and think of possible solutions thereafter..

Comment: I can only repeat. You don't need to add the `pwdReset` attribute. I implemented `ppolicy` into my webapp seven years ago without doing that, only adding `ppolicy.schema` and the overlay and a default policy entry, and it has been running perfectly ever since. If you got an error when setting it, you can't have the `ppolicy` overloay loaded correctly.